# Set the search directory for libraries when running executable

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I have a library which I compiled and linked to a test application. When running the test app, it tries to find the .so in a directory relative to the project directory, but since the application is being ran from the folder the executable is located in, it can't find the library. I want the app to look in the directory it's in for the library, so that I just need to make sure the .so is with the executable, do I have to pass some sort of argument to gcc when I compile to make this happen?

Comment: Would adding `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'` when compiling work? This adds the executable's working directory, whatever it may be at runtime, to the RPATH used by the runtime ld. That is a literal $ORIGIN there, not a shell variable, which is why one needs to quote it.

Comment: Interesting approach, I'll try that!

Comment: I should've said "containing directory" rather than "working directory" there, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach doesn't seem very Linux-y, libraries should be somewhere in /lib or /usr/lib, that's where the loader looks. If you have it in some other directory, you can try using `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=libpath` before running the program.

Another option is to open the library dynamically using dlopen, where you can provide the path.

```
dlopen(/path/to/library.so, RTLD_LAZY);
```

You can find a more complete example on dynamic .so loading here:
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/dl-libraries.html

You can also set the RPATH linker flag, so a given directory will always be searched for a certain library:

```
make LDFLAGS="-Wl,-R -Wl,/home/kris/src"
```

You can use the $ORIGIN built-in variable to refer to the current directory:

```
make CFLAGS="-fPIC" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath '-Wl,\$\$ORIGIN'"
```

Comment: Thank you! I will do that eventually but right now I'm making changes to it constantly and don't want to have to deal with moving it to /lib64 every time I compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify "PATH" when running your program. Compiler only needs third part libraries info during compiling and linking procedure. When the executable file is created, you can move third part libraries wherever you want.

Since you didn't tell which system you are on, you can try the following ways:

For Windows:

```
set PATH=your library path
```

For Linux:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=your library path
```

Comment: he did, in a way, the question is tagged with "linux" :)

Comment: Well, I didn't notice that. Thanks :)

Comment: I also said .so, as opposed to dll. Also said I was using GCC (not MinGW). Sorry if I wasn't clear, but thank you for providing a windows example! I'll need it later.

Answer (score -1):

You can include that library with full path name.

```
#include<absolute_path_name>
```

this will work.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a terrible option. Even if it works, it's absolutely unportable, *even on the very same computer*; if the code gets relocated, it needs to be altered.